# Conditional to Ignore Code in Android Unit Tests?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, testing

I have a thin wrapper `LogWrapper` around `android.util.Log` that I have used throughout most of my code.

When I write unit tests in my code, I often get an error like `Method "d" in android.util.Log`.

I don't want to have to write mock code in every single test for a basic logging function. I trust `android.util.Log` and I have basic tests for my `LogWrapper`.

So I want a way to tell the testing framework, don't bother with this bunch of code, a `notInTest` conditional.

Is there a way I can do this?

Example code

```
object LogCat {
    @JvmStatic
    @JvmOverloads
    fun debug(tag: String, message: String, throwable: Throwable? = null) {
        if (notInTest) { // This is what I want
            Log.d("$prefix:$tag", reduceLongMessage(message), throwable)
        }
    }
}
```